# jQuery or other way of adding <br> to lines in a select drop down list

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm also looking for how to implement a select where each line has a lot of information. I  only have a small horizontal space and I would like to do something like embed a 
 into a line. Tried this and it doesn't work. What solutions are available. I just would like some simple solution. Maybe with jQuery or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't span a select drop down item across multiple lines (i.e. word wrap). You'll need a custom select input box: possibly [this](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown) could help

Answer (score 0):

From what I can find, this is not possible using a normal `<select>` and `<option>` tag. I would suggest, however, you either:

- Create your own fake `<select>` using `<div>`s, that will support line breaks
- Use on of the stock online fake selects: [Fake Select - Google](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=fake%20select%20jquery)